# JAWS not reading input type text field value

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I am using JAWS in my application. In our application we have

```
<input type="text">
```

when we typing any thing, the screen reader is announcing that. But in speech viewer nothing is displaying.

Can anyone suggest me solution whether it is an issue from JAWS or any other configuration to make to read.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about the Speech History Viewer you access with `Space+Ins -> H`? That doesn't update on the fly, you need to close it and re-open it to see the speech history.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking about is the "typing echo" setting.  It has four settings: off, characters, words, and characters and words.  I have mine set to words so that when I'm typing in an input field, I do **not** hear each letter as I'm typing.  When I hit space to complete the word, then I hear the word I just typed.  The typing echo is an aid to verify what is being typed and is not really part of the interface (such as the input field's label) so what I'm typing will not show up in the speech history windows (Ins+Space, H).  Regular parts of the interface show up in the speech history window.

After you have typed in the field, if you move the focus off it and then back to it, **then** you will hear the contents of the field (what you had previously typed) because the value of the field is now part of the interface and will show up in the speech history window.